# Problems calling syscall function in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, system-calls

For a homework assignment, I have to modify the linux kernel.

I am working on a virtual machine, and I added a system call to the kernel, which I called `get_unique_id`. Here is the code for `get_unique_id.c` :

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

asmlinkage long sys_get_unique_id(int * uuid)
{
    // static because we want its state to persist between calls
    static int uid = 0;

    ++uid;

    // assign new uid value to user-provided mem location
    // returns non-zero if success or -EFAULT otherwise
    int ret = put_user(uid, uuid);
    return ret;
}
```

I also added this line to `syscalls.h` :

```
asmlinkage long sys_get_unique_id(int * uuid);
```

This line to syscall_32.tbl :

```
383 i386    get_unique_id       sys_get_unique_id
```

And finally this line to `syscall_64.tbl` :

```
548 common  get_unique_id       sys_get_unique_id
```

After recompiling and reloading the kernel, I wrote a little C program to test my system call, here is the code for the C test file :

```
// get_unique_id_test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include "syscalls_test.h"

int main(void)
{
    // initialize the ints we want
    int id1;
    int id2;

    // check the id's are unique and that no error occured
    for (int i = INT_MIN; i < INT_MAX - 1; i += 2) {
        long ret1 = get_unique_id(&id1);
        long ret2 = get_unique_id(&id2);

        if (ret1 != 0)
            printf("ERROR: get_unique_id returned: %ld\n", ret1);

        if (ret2 != 0)
            printf("ERROR: get_unique_id returned: %ld\n", ret2);

        if (id2 != id1 + 1)
            printf("ERROR: successive id's did not increment properly: id1 = %d, id2 = %d\n", id1, id2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And its header file :

```
// syscalls_test.h
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define __NR_get_unique_id 383

inline long get_unique_id(int * uuid)
{
    return syscall(__NR_get_unique_id, uuid) ? errno : 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, while trying to compile the C test file with the following command : `gcc -std=c99 get_unique_id_test.c -o get_unique_id_test`, I get the following error :

```
In file included from get_unique_id_test.c:4:0:
syscalls_test.h: In function ‘get_unique_id’:
syscalls_test.h:10:5: warning: implicit declaration of function        ‘syscall’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return syscall(__NR_get_unique_id, uuid) ? errno : 0;
     ^
syscalls_test.h: In function ‘get_unique_id’:
syscalls_test.h:10:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘syscall’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return syscall(__NR_get_unique_id, uuid) ? errno : 0;
     ^
/tmp/cc1euZ3r.o: In function `main':
get_unique_id_test.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `get_unique_id'
get_unique_id_test.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `get_unique_id'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It appears gcc cannot find the function `get_unique_id(int * uuid)`, which is declared in `syscalls_test.h`, and the `syscall` function, which should be declared, I believe, in `syscall.h`, right ?

I don't understand why this happens. Does anybody have an idea ?

**EDIT :** my problems were solved using a3f's solution (see below) **PLUS** moving the `#include "syscalls_test.h"` at the very top of the file, as he said in the comments. Thank you very much.

Comment: Start by adding `#define _GNU_SOURCE` to the top of your `syscalls_test.h`

Comment: FYI `sys_get_unique_id` is not thread-safe; multiple threads could call it simultaneously and get the same value. You could fix this with `atomic_t`.

Comment: Yes I know, for now my system call is very simple, but I am currently trying to make it thread safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including `unistd.h` or any other header as [`syscall(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) is not POSIX.
- Use `static inline` instead of plain `inline`. Plain `inline` supplies an inline definition, but the compiler is free to ignore it and use the external definition instead, which you aren't providing.

Comment: Thanks, adding `static` to my function solved the error. There's something I don't understand though, wouldn't it make the `get_unique_id` function invisible outside the `syscalls_test.h` file ?

Comment: And I added `#define _GNU_SOURCE` as you said, but I still get the warning of implicit function declaration of `syscall`. I get it only once though, not twice like before.

Comment: `#define` it as the very first thing, before including any headers. `static` makes a function internal to a translation unit, a file may `#include` multiple headers, so a translation unit may contain multiple files and the `static` function is accessible in all of them.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. About the `#define` though, I did put it as the very first line in the file, and I still get the warning.

Comment: Because you include files in `get_unique_id_test.c` before defining it. Either `#define` it at the very top or pass it on the command line.

Comment: @Scrashdown please update your original question with the changes you've made.

Comment: @kalaracey This is rarely a good idea, it's more important to keep the question and answer in-sync. If OP needs clarification, they can use comments. If they got a new question, they post a new one.

Comment: @a3f Ah I see. Its just that the comments are very hard to follow, and had made it sound like the problem was not resolved; but I guess later it was resolved, as the OP accepted your answer. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one:

```html
#include <unistd.h>
```